# Bluetooth API in Windows Phone developing

Tags: windows-phone-7, bluetooth

I'm working at Windows Phone application these days and have faced the problem with bluetooth file transfer management. The point is that I haven't find any useful information about a sort of Bluetooth API for Windows Phone developing on C#. Have you ever had the same problem? I will be very happy for every advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BT is not supported on WP7 at that moment.

Maybe this will be interesting for you: [DFT BT File Transfer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=22887886#post22887886)